# How can I create a Beamer presentation with Quarto from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, quarto, beamer

I'm trying to replicate the output from the following address:
[text](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-gallery/tree/main/presentations/beamer)

I have done the following:

1. Install Quarto.
2. Download an example beamer.qmd
3. Change it to a jupyter notebook file to view with: `quarto convert beamer.qmd`
4. To output it as a pdf file I used: `fourth render beamer.ipynb --to pdf`. But first I had to install the following `quarto install tinytex`.

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.9.0 and jupyter notebook and installed Quarto a couple of days ago, but I can't figure out how to render an ipynb document as a beamer presentation. And also I would like to use a theme from what is available "Beamer theme gallery".
Maybe my query is very basic, but if someone can help me I would be very grateful. Please.

Could you please help me with the steps and tools needed to render a file.ipynb to a beamer-type presentation using a format, for example, from the beamer gallery.

Comment: `quarto render z1.ipynb --to beamer`